# Jump diffusion model to work out probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

[image]

[image]

I'm not being able to understand firstly how they determined what the mean and variance of Xt=... is in the last sentence of the solution. Secondly I'm not able to understand where they got the 1 mu t>x in the step of the solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given that $X_t = \mu t + \sum_{i=1}^{N_t} \xi_i$. Note that the upper bound of the summation is random variable as well. Hence to compute $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ we need the law of total expectation:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X_t] &= \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{E}[X_t | N_t = n] \mathbb{P}[N_t = n] \nonumber \\
&= \sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{E}\left[\mu t+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i \ | \ N_t = n \right] \mathbb{P}[N_t = n]. 
\end{align}
Since $N_t$ is independent of $\xi_i$ we can write the last equality as 
$$\sum_{n \geq 0} \mathbb{E}\left[\mu t+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i \right] \mathbb{P}[N_t = n].$$
Now, note that the upper bound of the sum occurring in $\mu t + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i$ is no longer a random variable. Hence we have the sum of $n$ independent normally distributed random variables which is a normal distribution with parameter $n\alpha$ and $n\delta^2$. Furthermore, it is well known that if $X \sim N(\alpha,\delta^2)$ then $\mu t + X \sim N(\mu t+\alpha^2, \delta^2)$ (it's a translation of the normal distribution).

To answer your second question. The sum is split up as
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\mu t \leq x \right) e^{-\lambda t} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\mu t + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i \leq x \right) \frac{(\lambda t)^n e^{-\lambda t}}{n!}.$$
However, $\mu t$ and $x$ are numbers, hence $\mathbb{P}(\mu t \leq x) = 1$ if $\mu t \leq x$, otherwise this probability is equal to zero. This explains the use of the indicator function.